# Execute at block help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a way to execute at a block, but it is just not working. I am trying to make an ore scanner that activates when you hold an item named "Scanner" in your hand. I have the "activate when holding item" part done. Italics are optional or changeable commands.
COMMANDS:
Not working part:

`execute @p ~ ~ ~ /fill ~5 ~5 ~5 ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 minecraft:command_block 0 replace minecraft:iron_ore 0 {auto:1b,Command:"/summon shulker ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:\"Scanned\",NoGravity:1b,AttachFace:0,Color:15b,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,Glowing:1b}}`

execute @e[name=*Scanned*,type=shulker] ~ ~ ~ setblock *iron_ore* ~ ~ ~
kill @e[name=*Scanned*,type=shulker]

Use to execute command
`execute @e[name=Scanned,type=shulker] ~ ~ ~ COMMAND HERE`

Comment: How does this not work?  Do you get an error or something?

Comment: I get an error that says "could not execute command as player"

Comment: your `Command:" "` tag is never closed, meaning it's missing its second quotation mark. `}"}`

Comment: @Plagiatus I just tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: okay now I know the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:
you're missing a " to close the `Command:""` tag.

---

The next problem is this:

The syntax ([wiki for reference](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#fill)) for the fill/replace is

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <dataValue|state> replace [replaceTileName] [replaceDataValue]
```

There is no `[dataTag]` for the block to fill in there, it's not supported with the `replace` argument.

The non-replace syntax is this:

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> [dataValue|state] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

that means you have to work around that if you want to use fill/replace with a dataTag, for example like this:

- filling the areas air blocks with something you never need, like `structure_voids`,
- then replace the `iron_ore` blocks with air and
- then set the commandblock with `fill/keep` to replace all the air blocks.
- last, remove the placeholder blocks

Comment: That was laggy. But still did not work. The only way I see it could not work is executing, because the command is too long.

Comment: too long? commandblocks have a limit of 35.000 characters, i doubt this command will get too long anytime soon.

Comment: No, like the player executing a very long command due to the execute command.

Comment: it doesn't work like that. the moment it's run from a commandblock, even with execute on a player, the commandblock-rules apply and not the chat rules. make sure you actually run this in a commandblock. also, if that were the case, you'd get errors in the output. do you get any errors in the output?

Comment: I just had the replace iron ore with air command backwards. It works perfectly now that I flipped it back around.